# How to index formset input fields with list elements

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I use elements from a list as formset indexes instead of the generic 0,1,2 etc?
Right now I have something like:

```py
Sizes = ["XS", "S", "M","L", "XL"]
SizesFormSet = formset_factory(SizesForm, extra=len(Sizes))
```

And my formset input fields are indexed as 0,1,2... like so:

```html
<td><input type="number" name="Jaune-0-quantité" id="id_Jaune-0-quantité"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="Jaune-1-quantité" id="id_Jaune-1-quantité"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="Jaune-2-quantité" id="id_Jaune-2-quantité"></td>
...
```

and I'd like to index them as "XS", "S", "M"

````html
```html
<td><input type="number" name="Jaune-XS-quantité" id="id_Jaune-XS-quantité"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="Jaune-S-quantité" id="id_Jaune-S-quantité"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="Jaune-M-quantité" id="id_Jaune-M-quantité"></td>
````

The django documentation deals with renaming a formset input field prefix, but it doesn't deal with indexing.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question? Are these `choices` values for a field? Defining them as an `Enum` using `models.TextChoices` would automatically display the descriptions, not the indices ...

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way, not using formsets:

```py
#views.py
formsets = []
        for couleur in Couleurs:
            formset=[]
            for taille in Tailles:
                formset.append({"name": taille+"-"+couleur, "id": "id_"+taille+"-"+couleur})
            formsets.append({"formset":formset, "couleur":couleur})
return render(request, "front/nouvel-article.html", {'form': form, 'formsets': formsets, 'collection': collection, "tailles": [""]+Tailles})
```

and in my template:

```html
<form action="/nouvel-article/{{ collection }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Détails</legend>
                  {{ form|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Quantité</legend>
                  <table>
                    <thead>
                      {% for taille in tailles %}
                        <th>{{ taille }}</th>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {% for formset in formsets %}
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{formset.couleur}}</td>
                          {% for field in formset.formset %}
                            <td><input type="number" name="{{ field.name }}" id="{{ field.id }}"></td>
                          {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Confirmer</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```